# I ain't as good as I once was but I'm as good once as I ever was

Tags: meaning

I heard a song "As Good As I Once Was" by Toby Keith.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=kp&hl=id&v=ldQrapQ4d0Y&gl=ID

There is this part of the lyric that I don't really know the meaning, **"I ain't as good as I once was but I'm as good once as I ever was".**

By context of the video and the whole lyric I practically guess "I might not be as good as the younger me most of the time now, but if I could be that good at that time I can also be that good this time".

Am I correct?

The placement of "once" is kind of confusing me. I get the first "once", but I don't get the function of the second "once". An example of sentence using "once" with similar function would be great.

Comment: Kind of. Notice the contexts are sex and fighting. He's not as good as he (always) was when he was younger, but he's as good *one time* now as he ever was in his youth.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cowboy song lyrics.

Comment: And what makes it not English that it comes from a cowboy song?

Comment: @mplungjan - it's certainly English, but supposedly lyrics and poetry interpretation are OT here. What's worse, it's a cowboy song (and they are worse than many, except perhaps rap).

Comment: @medica That's fight'n talk. (Being a coward, I won't add that I agree.)

Comment: I'm sorry if this is off-topic, but the placement second "once" is kind of confusing me. I understand the first "once".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I ain't as good as I once was...

I'm not as good now as I used to be...

> ...but I'm as good once as I ever was

...but **for one time only** I can be as good as the best I was in the past.

That is, in general, he's deteriorated, but with a great effort he can equal his previous standard.